# txt document link on desktop opens with meld when should be gedit

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments

I created a link in ~/Desktop to a file notes.txt - which appears on the desktop (as 'Desktop icons' is enabled in gnome-shell-extensions)
I did this by Alt-drag of file from source directory to ~/Desktop using Files app then selecting 'Link Here' from the context menu that appears

In properties on the link the Link target is correctly /home/xxx/Documents/notes.txt
If on the desktop I right-click and choose open - it is opened by gedit
If I doubleclick meld gets loaded instead

If I double click the link in ~/Desktop from the Files app (not directly on the Desktop) it is opened by gedit

Checking the association:

```
~/Desktop$ mimeopen  notes.txt 
Opening "notes.txt" with Text Editor  (text/plain)
```

So something in the Gnome desktop is calling meld for /txt files when should be calling gedit

Doing the same thing with a jpg does not result in meld being loaded

I'm using  Ub 20.04.3

Comment: Could you check whether this behaviour persist after you logged out then back in?

Comment: yes it persists.    BTW when double-clicked meld is loaded 3 times in sucession

Comment: Issue is apparently with the Desktop Icons extensions. You may want to try Desktop Icons NG instead, used by default in Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: thanks - assume that is instead of gnome-shell-extension

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the GUI file manager. Right-click on the txt file and choose "Properties".  Go to the tab that says "Open With".  Change the default application from meld to whatever text editor you want.

Comment: This shows the text editor as default